# in intel-xdk apps how to assign app launcher icons in it?

Tags: intel-xdk

> **how to assign launch icon for the intel-XDK app like facebook app as blue-F as       launch icons?.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open project in launch icons and splash icons.  There we can edit our launch icons.

Answer (score 0):

[here we can insert the launcher icons in it useing these steps on the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7XhG.png)